# Getting parameter into external file

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am trying to embed vimeo video playlist script in module but I have problem with getting $token param.

This is file where I get the vimeo key, secret and token using official php library: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

outside-web-root-settings.php:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_module');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
    $vkey = $moduleParams->get('vimkey'); 
    $vsecret = $moduleParams->get('vimsecret'); 
    $vtoken = $moduleParams->get('vimtoken'); 

    $key = '$vkey'; 
    $secret = '$vsecret';
    $token = '$vtoken';
```

The script correctly get `$vkey` and `$vsecret` params but not the `$vtoken`. I get this error on console:

> You must provide a valid authenticated access token.

and I get this for the var_dump of the $vtoken

```
string(32) "3wsrsdf234mytoken2342werwr"
```

But when I change param $token to:

```
$token = '3wsrsdf234mytoken2342werwr';
```

Then script work properly. How can I fix this issue?

---

vimeo_data.php

```
require_once("../../outside-web-root-settings.php");

if(!isset($_REQUEST['type']) || !isset($_REQUEST['page']) || !isset($_REQUEST['per_page']) || IsNullOrEmpty($key) || IsNullOrEmpty($secret) || IsNullOrEmpty($token)) exit("PHP Vimeo information missing!");

function IsNullOrEmpty($v){
    return (!isset($v) || trim($v)==='');
}

$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
$per_page = $_REQUEST['per_page'];
$path = isset($_REQUEST['path']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['path']) ? $_REQUEST['path'] : null;
$user = isset($_REQUEST['user']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['user']) ? $_REQUEST['user'] : null;
$query = isset($_REQUEST['query']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['query']) ? $_REQUEST['query'] : null;
$sort = isset($_REQUEST['sort']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['sort']) ? $_REQUEST['sort'] : 'date';

require("../autoload.php");
use Vimeo\Vimeo;
$vimeo = new Vimeo($key, $secret, $token);



if($type == 'vimeo.channel'){

    //Get a list of videos in a Channel - https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/channels/{channel_id}/videos
    $result = $vimeo->request("/channels/$path/videos", array(
                                                    'page'=> $page,
                                                    'per_page' => $per_page,
                                                    'fields' => 'uri,name,description,duration,width,height,privacy,pictures.sizes',
                                                    'sort' => $sort,
                                                    'direction' => 'asc',                                   
                                                    'query' => $query));

}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../..' ));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT params FROM #__modules WHERE module = 'mod_module'");

$module = $db->loadObject();
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);

    $key = $moduleParams->get('vimkey'); 
    $secret = $moduleParams->get('vimsecret'); 
    $token = $moduleParams->get('vimtoken');
```

Answer (score 3):

[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) says:

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

So

```
$token = '$vtoken';
```

will result in string `$vtoken`, not `3wsrsdf234mytoken2342werwr`. Try to `echo $token;` and see that it dosen't have value what you expect.

Remove the unneccessary quotes or assign your variables directly from `$moduleParams`:

```
$key    = $moduleParams->get('vimkey'); 
$secret = $moduleParams->get('vimsecret'); 
$token  = $moduleParams->get('vimtoken');
```

Comment: Thank your for the response @Rene. Unfortunately, it did't help. I also tried with double quotes, without quotes and echo. I  always get error for double or single quotes `You must provide a valid authenticated access token.` and without quotes: `Php Vimeo information missing`

Comment: If you get `Php Vimeo information missing`, this means that you are going further. So use without quotes and investigate your `$vimeo->request`.

Comment: I get this `string(13) "('vimtoken');"` for var_dump of `$token  = "$moduleParams->get('vimtoken')";` Does this mean that the paramenter isn't get correctly?

Comment: Yes, it means that. Remove quotes.

Comment: So it dosen't get module params. Try `print_r($module->params);` and see what you get.

Comment: And the problem was?